# Refresh the DataTable plugin table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, datatables

I used the Data Tables.

DataTables is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library.

The data table have more than one page, for example if I delete a data from the second page of datatable, the page should continue in the second page, but here that is moved to the first page.

Answer (score 2):

https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29#

Ex.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Sort by column 1 and then re-draw
table
    .order( [[ 1, 'asc' ]] )
    .draw( false );
```

.draw(false); should have it redraw without changing pages.

Or, to do this after removing a row:

```
$('#yourTable').DataTable().row($(tr)).remove().draw(false);
```